# Export part of table definition using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to export part of MySQL table definition using phpMyAdmin?

I need to transfer 2 columns from one table to other DB, so I expect 2 "ALTER TABLE" SQL commands to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no built in way to do this, but [Schema Sync - a MySQL Schema Versioning and Migration Utility](http://schemasync.org/) can be used:

*Schema Sync will generate the SQL necessary to migrate the schema of a source database to a target database (patch script), as well as a the SQL necessary to undo the changes after you apply them (revert script).*